# Изображение в ImageView с сохранением размера изображения

Tags: android, android-sdk, android-imageview

Всем привет. Есть `ImageView` и иконка изображения. Как можно поместить ее в `imageView`, чтобы она располагалась по центру и с сохранением размера (24 x 24dp)? В идеале поместить иконку в `xml` файл с возможностью изменять background.

Answer (score 0):

Для того, тобы картинка помещенная в ImageView была без растягивания - используйте атрибут `android:scaleType="centerInside"` в xml